# I would like to print the number of values > 1 in each list, in a list of lists

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

```
> test=binary[1:5,6:8];test
  wHa wMel wNo
1   1    1   0
2   1    1   1
3   1    1   0
4   1    1   1
5   1    1   0
```

I've created all combinations of column comparisons.

```
> t_combs=combn(test,2,simplify = F);t_combs
[[1]]
  wHa wMel
1   1    1
2   1    1
3   1    1
4   1    1
5   1    1

[[2]]
  wHa wNo
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   1   0
4   1   1
5   1   0

[[3]]
  wMel wNo
1    1   0
2    1   1
3    1   0
4    1   1
5    1   0
```

I've computed row sums for each row in each column comparison.

```
> lapply(t_combs,rowSums)
[[1]]
1 2 3 4 5 
2 2 2 2 2 

[[2]]
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 1 2 1 

[[3]]
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 1 2 1
```

I would like to know how to print the number of items in each list with a value > 1. My desired output would be:

```
[[1]]
5

[[2]]
2

[[3]]
2
```

How can I write code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, we can do the `rowSums` and then create a logical index to `sum`.  TRUE/FALSE is converted to binary `1/0`.  Thus, if there are 5 TRUE, then `sum` would be `5`

```
lapply(t_combs,function(x) sum(rowSums(x) > 1))
#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(wHa = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), wMel = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), wNo = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. I'm confused about how to convert the binary values in each of my three listed tables to logical indices.

Comment: I'm confused why you referenced TRUE/FALSE in your answer. I don't have any TRUE/FALSE data. As you can see I've already used rowSums to produce sums of each row. For each of my resulting "rowSum" lists, I want to know how to count up the number of values that are > 1.

Comment: @Digsby  Okay.  It is the result of `lapply(t_combs,function(x)  rowSums(x) >1)`

Comment: It is anonymous function or lambda function which is kind of creating a function on the fly instead of `f1 <- function(x) rowSums(x) > 1`

Comment: Okay when I run that code it gives me 3 lists where 1 is replaced by TRUE and 0 is replaced by FALSE. How can I count up the number of TRUE and FALSE in each list?